# Retrieving JSON array elements based on their values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json object stored in MySQL as:

```
{"PhysicalAddresses": {
"Entry": [
{"Key": "Home", "City": "City1", "State": "ST", "Street": "Some old street", "PostalCode": "00000", "CountryOrRegion": null},
{"Key": "Business", "City": "City2", "State": "ST", "Street": "A much nicer street", "PostalCode": "00000", "CountryOrRegion": null}
]}}
```

I want to grab the business address: something like

```
json_extract(column,"$.PhysicalAddresses.Entry[*](where Key=Business)")
```

What can I put into the "where Key=Business" to make this work, or is there no way to search JSON in MySQL this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON Path Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-path-syntax) allows you to search for a value or subdocument at a path, but it doesn't have any syntax for testing values found at a given path.

This is a case where *NOT* using JSON would be a better approach. Store each entry in a row of a separate table, and the fields of the entry as independent columns. Then the query is much simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM PhysicalAddresses WHERE `Key` = 'Business'
```

It's ironic that so many people say that they use JSON for flexibility. It does give you flexibility in allowing you to *insert* a variety of data formats, but you sacrifice flexibility on the ways to *query* the data subsequently.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the array you want with **SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(column,"$.PhysicalAddresses.Entry[1].Key")** from table; but that depends on having 'Business' always in the second position of the array.

I am going to suggest using something like **SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(column,"$.PhysicalAddresses.Entry[*].Key") from table;**  which will return  ["Home", "Business"] and then parsing in your application or working with **JSON_CONTAINS()**